# SKLabelNode disappears when text is changed

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I am trying to create a sklabelnode that displays the score of a sprite kit game. The text displays 0 initially, but disappears when the text is changed. The node is declared globally after the class declaration along with the score, that's an int. Here's the code:

```
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    scoreLabel.text = String(score)
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 48
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)-50)

    self.addChild(scoreLabel)
}
func updateScoreAndLabel()->(scoreint:Int,label:SKLabelNode){
    score++
    scoreLabel.text = String(score)
    return (score, scoreLabel)
}
```

updateScoreAndLabel() is called from another function that isn't important for this question so I did not include it. The problem is not in the function call I believe.

Comment: Have you tried changing the zPosition property of the SKLabelNode? Depending on **when** you've added it in the view hierarchy, it may be present, but behind your other nodes.

Comment: That worked perfectly, I just had to give it a higher zPosition. Thanks a lot, mate. @ClayMcIlrath

Comment: NP man, glad to help. Accept and close if you will. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just putting this here as an official answer in case someone else comes across it, and since it's the accepted answer by the OP.

Try setting the zPosition property of the SKLabelNode to a high value. Depending on when you've added it in the view hierarchy, it may be present, but behind your other nodes.

Comment: That fixed it but it still doesn't explain that strange behaviour. I would expect that if the label node is visible at one point it will stay visible, even if one changes the text for it. If the zPosition is not changed manually, of course.